# keyframes relative (vw) font-size weird behavior in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, font-size, keyframe

I have a text element that uses a font size of 7vw and sizes correctly with IE. I want to play an animation on it that changes font-size over time from 7vw to 10vw and back to 7vw, but the 7vw in the keyframe animation is at least 10 times as big as the 7vw already applied to the element.

I have tried to use other units like em, pt and %. I have also tried setting body font-size in order to use the em unit. Furthermore I tried to parent it to other elements in the HTML, but to no avail.

```css
.text-bot {
    padding-top: 10vw;
    font: bold 7vw Calibri;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #009999;
    z-index: 50;
    -webkit-animation: text-bounce 1s linear;
    -moz-animation: text-bounce 1s linear;
    animation: text-bounce 1s linear;
}

@keyframes text-bounce {
    0% {
        font-size: 7vw;
    }

    10% {
        font-size: 12vw;
    }

    100% {
        font-size: 7vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<b class="text-bot anim-text" id="count">0</b>
```

I expected the 7vw to remain 7vw given the fact that the animation is applying it to the same element. What happens instead is that the 7vw from the animation jumps out of all bounds, more than 10 times the expected size.
If I remove the animation from .text-bot it is all sized correctly and working well.

This is all in IE, Chrome was easy to setup (I also have webkit keyframes identical to the IE ones).

Sizing up the window while the animation is playing makes the text get bigger and bigger until it hits a point and it starts from the smallest size and continues to get bigger again in a loop (Depending on how much I increase the window size). Something like small, medium, large, xlarge, small, medium, large, xlarge, small, etc, dependent on how large the browser window is.

Note: Try the script in Chrome and then compare in IE to see the difference. The IE one jumps in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get it to work with css. I tried zoom, but that was bugged in IE too. I solved it with the following JQuery code:

```
        $('#count').stop().animate({ fontSize: '8vw' }, { duration: 100 })
            .animate({ fontSize: '7vw' }, {
                duration: 900
            });
```

I am still interested in a keyframe solution.